# Writing Case statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ, i need to write a LINQ statement with CASE statement. I am trying to convert the following query to linq. Here 1 and 0 are boolean. How can i achive this

```
Select CASE [db].[table] WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN 0 THEN 'No' END AS Options from table
```

I tried the following but now working

```
Options = table.Options  = 1 ? "Yes" : table.Options  = 0 ? "No"
```

Comment: _"but now working"_ so there's no issue anymore? If you mean `not` instead, in what way does it now work, do you get an exception? If so, what kind of exception?

Comment: Surely this is, `tables.ToList().Select(x => x.Options == 1 ? "Yes" : "No");`

Comment: `Select CASE [db].[table]` is not valid in SQL since `[db].[table]` is a table and not a column.

Comment: show your full linq,please

Comment: `=` is the [assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx), you are probably looking for `==`

Comment: Better to show your table structure / data ?

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things you've done wrong - one, the syntax of the ternary operator is

```
condition ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse
```

Second, you need to use the equality operator (`==`) for comparison, not the assignment (`=`) operator.

Thus, `table.Options  = 1 ? "Yes" : table.Options  = 0 ? "No"` should be replaced with

```
table.Options == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Depending on your actual LINQ provider, there might be a helper to allow you to build SQL-like `case` expressions (both the conditional and the choice-y type), but that's impossible to say without knowing exactly what you're using. If there is no helper, you'll have to do with the ternary operator (which is a bit crazy to read for more than a single condition, but oh well...).

For example, my LINQ provider uses the following syntax:

```
Case(table.Options).When(1, "Yes").Else("No").End()
```

or

```
Case().When(table.Options == 1, "Yes").Else("No").End()
```

But again, the only standard way is the ternary operator. Have a look in the documentation of your particular LINQ provider to see if it supports the SQL-like `case` expressions and how.

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the table:
I would try:

```
Options = db.table.ToList().Select(X => X.Options == 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change to:

```
Options = table.Options == 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: as i said earlier i am checking with bool value, here i am getting error Constant value 1 cannot be converted to bool

Comment: That's because you have table.Options = 1. Like I said, change to double =, as in  "table.Options==1"

Comment: @chrisl08 Add that configuration to your answer body.

Comment: Can't use == because Operator == cannot be applied to oprands of type bool and int

Comment: Then table.Options is a boolean field.  Try: Options = table.Options ? "Yes" : "No";